# XMLHTTPRequest or Fetch with partial URL

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

Assuming a server has several files such as FileName_1.ext, FileName_2.ext, ... etc.  is there a way to use Java script to return a list of these files names which would match a pattern of "FileName_WC.ext"  if wild cards were permitted.   I assume in advance I do not know the number of such files nor the actual fields represented by the "WC"  which would likely be date strings. (I am using WC instead of an asterisk in my text since this editor did not allow the asterisk to appear as text. )

Comment: Do you have access to the server or is it a remote server?

Answer (score 2):

Not in the general case. There is no standard for an HTTP server to return a list of known URLs under a given path.

If your server had a non-standard means to do that (e.g. Apache HTTPD’s directory listings or your own custom JSON based web-service) then you could request that and then parse and filter the response client-side.